# custom email authentication backend not working in django 2.1.4

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-login

I am having trouble in integrating custom authentication backend in `django 2.1.4` . Following is my code : 
 my `FMS.authBackend` module :

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class authEmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        print("aaaaaaa")
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        return None
```

my `settings.py` :

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
                'FMS.authBackend.authEmailBackend',
                'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

                )
```

my `urls.py` :

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
urlpatterns = [ 
        path('login', my_decos.logout_required(auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name = 'register/login.html')),name = 'login')
]
```

The above code is not working in my case. Function `authenticate` in `authEmailBackend` is never called as nothing printed in console but I print statement in `authenticate` function.

although the same code was working for `django 2.0.8`, the only difference then was that the `urls.py` was :

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
urlpatterns = [ 
        path('login', my_decos.logout_required(auth_views.login(template_name = 'register/login.html')),name = 'login')
]
```

but in the newer django the `django.contrib.auth.views.login` doesn't support any more and we need to use `django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView`. I read somewhere that to use custom `AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND` our url must point to `django.contrib.auth.views.login` but which is not possible here.

So can you please help me to overcome the problem.

Answer (score 7):

[request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) argument need to pass to the authenticate method

```
  class authEmailBackend(ModelBackend):
        **def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):**
            print("aaaaaaa")
            UserModel = get_user_model()
            try:
                user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)
            except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
                return None
            else:
                if user.check_password(password):
                    return user
            return None
```

Comment: we didn't need it in earlier versions?

Comment: [**HttpRequest**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/1.11/#django-contrib-auth) is passed to authenticate from django 1.11